# ReactiveX in scala-swing doesn't work?

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, scala-swing

I'm newbie to reactivex, and try to use it with scala-swing.

My code is quite simple, but it doesn't work:

```
import rx.lang.scala.Observable

import scala.swing.{Frame, MainFrame, SimpleSwingApplication, TextField}

object HelloReactiveX extends SimpleSwingApplication {

  val input = new TextField()

  override def top: Frame = new MainFrame {
    title = "Hello, reactivex"
    contents = input
  }

  val stream = Observable[String] { subscriber =>
    println("before input.subscribe")
    input.subscribe {
      case _ => {
        println("input changed: " + input.text)
        subscriber.onNext(input.text)
      }
    }
    println("after input.subscribe")
  }

  stream.subscribe(t => println("###: " + t))

}
```

The dependency is:

```
"org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-swing" % "1.0.1",
"io.reactivex" %% "rxscala" % "0.25.0",
```

The strange thing is there is nothing printed to the console!

Is there anything wrong in my code?

PS: The live project is here https://github.com/freewind/scala-swing-demo/blob/fc79c5b65e6fecc21d3894888d336d8f5204f62e/src/main/scala/scalaswing/HelloReactiveX.scala

Comment: Your code works fine for me

Comment: I just found it's not working with jdk 1.6, but ok with 1.8

Comment: @Freewind Feel free to put  your comment as an answer. give it  some more detail if you can and then accept it. 

The extra detail can be very useful for someone else that bumps into the same problem.